# How to handle VB.NET LINQ object reference not set exception?

Tags: vb.net

```
Dim IsValid = From rec In Collection.QueryPalletID("").AsEnumerable() _
                        Join rec In thedata.AsEnumerable() On lrec.ID.Trim Equals srec.Field(Of String)("ID").Trim _
                        Select rec

For Each rec As DataRow In IsValid 
    Exit For
Next
```

`For Each` throws Object reference not set exception. How to handle this exception?

Comment: Can you check your sample code please - there are two `rec`s and `lrec`/`srec` aren't defined.

Comment: Why do you have to define rec as a datarow in your for?  If you change it to `For Each rec in IsValid` it should work.  IsValid was never converted to a datatable, therefore you are comparing an object IsValid with a row in rec.  If there are values in IsValid, it will enter the for loop and exit the for loop... If there aren't any values in IsValid it will just skip the for loop...

Answer (score 0):

The root cause of the problem is likely the following expression

```
lrec.ID.Trim Equals srec.Field(Of String)("ID").Trim
```

One of the values here is `Nothing`.  Which is impossible to determine with the limited code sample.  My immediate suspcion would be `lrec` or `srec` since they aren't defined in the code sample but it could just as easily be `lrec.ID` or `src.Field(Of String)("ID")`

Once the `IsValid` collection is enumerated with `For Each` these expressions are executed and throw an exception when `Nothing` is accessed.  You need to fix these to account for `Nothing` or be initialized to a value

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

PS: I've written it on the fly, maybe you should do changes on the datatypes but just is to show you a (maybe) possible way to validate it.

```
Dim DataRows As IEnumerable(Of DataRow) =
    From rec As DataRow In Collection.QueryPalletID("").AsEnumerable()
    Join rec As DataRow In thedata.AsEnumerable() On lrec.ID.Trim Equals srec.Field(Of String)("ID").Trim
    Select rec

Dim IsValid As Boolean = 
    If(DataRows IsNot Nothing, 
       (From [Datarow] As DataRow In DataRows Where [Datarow] IsNot Nothing).Any),
       False)


If IsValid Then

    For Each rec As DataRow In DataRows
        Exit For
    Next rec

End If
```

Comment: Please help in Boolean syntax, after .Any False is not taking.

Comment: now it shows keyword is not valid as an identifier. Plz help me on this.